# What does mean marker in [ ] at packages.debian.org

Tags: linux, debian, packages

Sorry if my question is stupid, but I really can't find answer to it.
I list packages names and description for debian at packages.debian.org and sometimes see mark in [ ] in packages name like **[security]** and very interested in their's meaning.

I find some information about "Contrib" and "Non-Free" at [www.debian.org/distrib/packages](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages), but I can't find for others.
 So **What does mean marker in [ ] at packages.debian.org?**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a classification indicating what the particular package pertains but check out https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#s-priorities and see if that looks related to your question any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[security]` is used to indicate that a security update is available for the `package` to solve a security issue.

To apply the security update the security repository should be enabled on your `sources.list`.

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
```

If you are using a `non-free` software you should add:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

But...?

> Q: [How is security handled for `contrib` and `non-free`?](https://www.debian.org/security/faq#contrib)
>
> A: The short answer is: it's not. Contrib and non-free aren't official parts of the Debian Distribution and are not released, and thus not supported by the security team. **Some non-free packages are distributed without source or without a license allowing the distribution of modified versions. In those cases no security fixes can be made at all**. If it is possible to fix the problem, and the package maintainer or someone else provides correct updated packages, then the security team will generally process them and release an advisory.

Next step run:

```
# apt update && apt upgrade
```

To upgrade your package including the security update.

The [`unattended-upgrades`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/unattended-upgrades) is useful to automatically apply the security updates.

> [Debian wiki:](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades)
>
> The purpose of unattended-upgrades is to keep the computer current with the latest security (and other) updates automatically.

e,g:

```
apt-cache policy libvpx4
libvpx4:
  Installé : 1.6.1-3
  Candidat : 1.6.1-3+deb9u1
 Table de version :
     1.6.1-3+deb9u1 500
        500 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.6.1-3 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The current `libvpx4` installed version is `1.6.1-3` is a vulnerable package [CVE-2017-13194](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-13194) (installed from the `main` repo) should be upgraded (high Urgency) to the [`libvpx_1.6.1-3+deb9u1`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libvpx-dev) version, this update is available from the `security` repository.

> Package: libvpx-dev (1.6.1-3+deb9u1) [security]